# tkinter windows don't go away after being destroyed

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi, focus

I am writing a python script to display images, play music, and show a video on a raspberry pi when inputs are triggered. While i was working on this project I decided I wanted to add a webcam into the script. I played around with different webcam streamers until I found MPlayer which seemed to have the fastest frame rate and used the least resources. problem was, the MPlayer gui was hidden behind the tkinter windows that I was using to display the images. I tried several different things to bring the MPlayer window to the front and to make the tkinter windows go away but nothing seemed to work. Here's my code:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import subprocess
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    import Tkinter
    tkinter = Tkinter
else:
    import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import board
import neopixel

x=1
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(board.D10, 38)
pixels.fill((0, 0, 0))
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(25,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(27,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(22,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(24,GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(25,GPIO.LOW)

def showPIL(pilImage, exVar = 0):
    try:
        root.withdraw()
        root.destroy()
        root.update()
    except:
        pass
    root = tkinter.Toplevel()
    if x == 1:
        w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
    else:
        w, h = 100, 100
    root.overrideredirect(1)
    root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))
    #root.focus_set()
    root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: (e.widget.withdraw(), e.widget.quit()))
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root,width=w,height=h)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.configure(background='black')
    imgWidth, imgHeight = pilImage.size
    if imgWidth > w or imgHeight > h:
        ratio = min(w/imgWidth, h/imgHeight)
        imgWidth = int(imgWidth*ratio)
        imgHeight = int(imgHeight*ratio)
        pilImage = pilImage.resize((imgWidth,imgHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(w/2,h/2,image=image)
    root.update()

showPIL(Image.open("Data/blank.png"))
while not GPIO.input(4):
    pass
music = subprocess.Popen(['cvlc', '/home/pi/Desktop/Data/music.mp3'])
showPIL(Image.open("Data/trophy.png"))
time.sleep(1)
GPIO.output(22,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(0.5)
GPIO.output(27,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(0.5)
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(0.5)
GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
showPIL(Image.open("Data/poison.png"))
pixels.fill((0, 255, 0))
os.system("pkill tk")
x=0
showPIL(Image.open("Data/blank.png"))
x=1
camera = subprocess.Popen(['mplayer', '-fs', 'tv://'])
os.system("wmctrl -a MPlayer")
time.sleep(8)
camera.kill()
os.system("omxplayer -b '/home/pi/Desktop/Data/movie.mp4'")
showPIL(Image.open("Data/gun.png"))
GPIO.output(24,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(25,GPIO.HIGH)
while not GPIO.input(23):
    pass
pixels.fill((0, 0, 0))
showPIL(Image.open("Data/dumbell.png"))
time.sleep(1)
showPIL(Image.open("Data/pipe.png"))
time.sleep(1)
showPIL(Image.open("Data/noose.png"))
time.sleep(1)
music.kill()
showPIL(Image.open("Data/blank.png"))
end = subprocess.Popen(['cvlc', '/home/pi/Desktop/Data/end.wav'])
time.sleep(8)
end.kill()
```

Comment: @Goyo right after I declare the function showPIL the code attempts to destroy the window. sorry about the length of the code I just didn't want to leave anything out

Comment: In showPil you refer to a 'root' which you didnt declare (you catch the exception with a pass, so python didnt tell you that ;))

Comment: the line that should close the window is
    try:
        root.withdraw()
        root.destroy()
        root.update()
    except:
        pass

Comment: I dont know if you did, but somewhere you need a tkinter root: root = tkinter.Tk(). A tktinter.Toplevel() is a toplevel window

Comment: what would that change if i were to add that in

Comment: You don't know whether you are destroying the window or not. You are just trying. You won't know if something goes wromg because you are actively hiding any information about it. Don't do that.

Comment: The reason it has the try on it is because the first time the function runs the root variable doesn't exist. I could try getting rid of that

Comment: Not only the first time but every time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there are a few key problems here.

One massive problem is your `try/except` statement.

Your try except is always going to do `pass`. There is never going to be a time where you can `destroy()` something and then call `update()` on it. This will always result in an error and therefor the except statement of `pass` will run.

Next `root = tkinter.Toplevel()` is a problem. Because you never define the tkinter instance or what `root` should be you create a toplevel window instead and this will result in an instance of tkinter being opened but without a variable name to work with. That said root here is only defined locally to the function and thus any time the function is called again there is not record of root for the function to try to destroy because it has not been created yet as far as the function knows. You will need to define your root as a `global` variable for something like this.

Even if this works for you there should be 2 problems. One is an extra blank window showing up and 2 is that window not closing on its own when you close the toplevel window.

Next you are trying to use `sleep` while also running a tkinter instance. These things are not compatible without the use of threading so you need to either work threading into this or preferable learn how to use `after()`. `After()` is how tkinter manages timed events.

Instead of using `Toplevel()` here you needto be using `Tk()`. Instead of destroying and rebuilding your GUI each update you should just update your window instead. Going on the scope of what you are attempting to do you should probably play around a bit more with tkinter and learn how the event manager works before trying the raspberry pi project. Once you have a sold grasp on the Tkinter GUI and its event based process you will be able to do the more complicated stuff easier.

Comment: Also, `root` is local to the function. When the function returns, `root` isn't known anymore. When the function runs for the second time it doesn't "remember" a local variable from the last time it ran. So every statement in the `try` block will lead to an error every time because `root` is not defined.

Comment: @fhdrsdg you know I was thinking about that while writing my answer and forgot to add it. Thanks for pointing that out.